# Excel VBA - How do I Create a Button Depressed Effect for a Custom Macro Shape Button?

Tags: excel, vba, image, user-interface, button

I have created a custom shape to use as a Macro button in Excel. Initially, I was using the default Excel macro button, but wanted to make the spreadsheet look more modern. I have achieved what I was seeking in that regard, but now the buttons do not provide any feedback when you click them- they just load the Macro. With the original buttons, pressing them would provide a depression effect. I would like to simulate this effect with the new shape.

After searching solutions on the internet, I found one that worked.. once. It simulated a button click for a fraction of a second and loaded the macro. After the first use, it stopped working all together. I tried creating a new subroutine, but it did not help. I also added a sleep step at the recommendation of the site I found it on, and it did not have any effect either. Here's the code I am using:

```
Sub SimulateButtonClick2()
Dim vTopType As Variant
Dim iTopInset As Integer
Dim iTopDepth As Integer

'Record original button properties
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        vTopType = .BevelTopType
        iTopInset = .BevelTopInset
        iTopDepth = .BevelTopDepth
    End With

'Button Down
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = msoBevelSoftRound
        .BevelTopInset = 24
        .BevelTopDepth = 8
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
      Sleep 250
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Button Up - set back to original values
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ThreeD
        .BevelTopType = vTopType
        .BevelTopInset = iTopInset
        .BevelTopDepth = iTopDepth
    End With
    
Call checker

End Sub
```

I am assigning this macro to the button and calling the macro I need using "Call checker" at the end.

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a *lot* of extra fluff just to simulate the visual clicking of a button. What's wrong with a form control?

Comment: I also can't reproduce your issue. I actually get an error at `Sleep` because that is not a defined sub or function.  After removing that line it works fine. The real question is what is going on in your `checker` subroutine? That may be affecting the button from running again.

Comment: @dwirony I have it defined above using `Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)`. I have it connected to a simple code that just returns the value of a variable for testing purposes, but what I am trying to connect it to is actually a pretty long and complex code that generates a bill of materials. I wish I could share it but it is technically proprietary information so I am unable to. Is there anything  I could look out for?

Comment: @dwirony Yeah it definitely is a lot of work for not much reward. However, this excel document will ideally be used instead of legacy software at our company, and one of the advantages of it is modernization. So, I figured this is a good way to execute that.

Comment: Please, add `DoEvents` in the line above `Sleep 250`... I think, it does something but you cannot see the effect if the called sub `checker` has a `MsgBox` or a form to be shown, which does not let you see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: updated to add alternative approach to pause until mouse button is released

This worked fine for me, using a loop with Timer and Doevents:

```vb
'add the 64-bit version if you need to support that...
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Long

Sub Tester()
    
    SimulateButtonClick ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    
    Debug.Print "clicked!"

End Sub

'is the left mouse button down?
Function MouseIsDown() As Boolean
    MouseIsDown = GetAsyncKeyState(&H1)
End Function

Sub SimulateButtonClick(shp As shape)
    Dim vTopType As Variant, iTopInset As Integer, iTopDepth As Integer, t
    With shp.ThreeD
        vTopType = .BevelTopType 'Record original button properties
        iTopInset = .BevelTopInset
        iTopDepth = .BevelTopDepth
        .BevelTopType = msoBevelSoftRound
        .BevelTopInset = 8
        .BevelTopDepth = 8
        t = Timer

        '#1: use this loop for a temporary "pressed" effect 
        Do While Timer - t < 0.1
            DoEvents
        Loop
        'OR
        '#2: use this loop to wait until mouse button is let up
        Do While MouseIsDown
            DoEvents
            If Timer > (t + 10) Then Exit Do 'in case of glitches...
        Loop

        .BevelTopType = vTopType
        .BevelTopInset = iTopInset
        .BevelTopDepth = iTopDepth
        DoEvents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way I could make the button stay depressed as long as the mouse button is depressed? That helps a lot though! Thank you so much!

Comment: Added some code above to show how to wait for the mouse button to be released

Comment: Thank you so much! It's perfect! I just had to add PtrSafe after declare and it worked perfectly.